# Data Binding & WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, .net-4.5

I've come across an interesting situation whilst starting to work with the WPF framework.

I have the following code to create an ObservableCollection of type **Foo**

```
ObservableCollection<Foo> myFoo;
```

Foo has the following Properties:

- String Name
- String Folder
- ObservableCollection Items

Both Name and Folder have the OnPropertyChanged event implemented (Items already uses ObservableCollection so I believe no additional implementation work is necessary).

For every item within myFoo I would like to show the following:

- Name
- Folder
- Every value of FileInfo.FullName within Items.

e.g.

- Test Name 1
- Test Folder 1
- FileA.JPG
- FileB.JPG
- FileC.PNG
- Test Name 2
- Test Folder 2
- FileD.JPG
- FileE.JPG
- FileF.JPG

I've implemented the binding for the Name and Folder properties, however I'm not too sure on how I should implement binding the value of each Items.FileInfo.FullName occurance.

Would I need to implement a Converter?

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Which UI control you are using to show items ?

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann Looks to be just what I need, if you add your comment as an answer i'll gladly accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look into [`HierarchicalDataTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx). Maybe start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310666/recursive-hierarchicaldatatemplate-wpf).